# Notificación de acceso por ssh

Tags: linux, bash, eficiencia

Me gustaría saber, ¿cómo puedo lograr el mismo resultado que el siguiente script en Bash usando PAM_EXEC?

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -fn0 /var/log/auth.log | \
while read line;
do
    LOG=$(echo $line | grep "Accepted");
    if [ $? = 0 ];
    then
        if [ ! -d $HOME/.var/log ]; then mkdir -p $HOME/.var/log; fi
        echo $LOG >> $HOME/.var/log/auth.log
        USER=$(echo $LOG | grep -oP '(?<=for ).*(?= from)');
        IP=$(echo $LOG | grep -oP '(?<=from ).*(?= port)');
        HOSTNAME=$(hostname -f);
        DATE=$(date +'%c');
        notify-send -i dialog-warning "SSH Access" "User $USER@$HOSTNAME logged in from $IP\non $DATE.";
    fi
done
```

En el código anterior se ve como la información de las conexiones por ssh se extraen del archivo de registro `/var/log/auth.log`, sin embargo me parece que debería existir un mecanismo más optimo para esto.

He visto que con `pam_exec` se pueden ejecutar script o comandos al momento de hacer login, pero no veo una forma de hacerlo y pasar al script los argumentos necesarios: USER, IP.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow :) Te invito a revisar cómo incluir en tu pregunta un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a la vez que explicitar qué tipo de eficiencia buscas, de modo que tu pregunta pueda tener una respuesta específica y objetiva. Saludos.

Comment: Puedes echar una mirada a [multilog](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html). Manera djb es bien eficiente.

Comment: ¿ No seria mas simple modificar `/etc/profile`, o crear un archivo en `/etc/profile.d` ? PAM_EXEC creo recordar que está diseñado para realizar montajes con comandos específicos, no para esas cosas.

Comment: @Trauma igual funciona con un poco de sed y awk. Cuando la pregunta se reabre tengo una solución, si quiere usar pam_exec.

Comment: @Trauma gracias por tu comentario, el problema de esa solución que propones con los `profiles` es que la notificación debe ser mostrada a algunos usuarios específicos y que estén por la interfaz gráfica; no a cada uno de los usuarios que se autentiquen en el sistema.

Comment: @LuisDaniel puedes modificar los profiles para llamar a un programa externo que se encarga de decidir si se muestra o no la notificación, y a quién. No te lo puedo confirmar ahora, pero creo que si accedes por `SSH`, en el entorno se crea una variable que lo indica.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres usar `pam_exe` puedes aprovecharte del hecho que `pam_exe` se ejecuta en el entorno del usuario que se esta conectando. Por eso, `who am i` te da un dato como:

```
luser   pts/0        2017-02-17 13:27 (192.168.100.23)
```

De eso puedes extraer el uid (en el ejemplo "luser") y el ip (el valor en parentesis):

```
#!/bin/bash
LUSER=`who am i | awk '{print $1}'`
IPADDR=`who am i | awk '{print $5}' | sed -e 's/^(//' -e 's/)//'`
echo $LUSER
echo $IPADDR
```

en vez del `echo` puedes escribir los datos en un log.

El problema con este método es que corre con derechos del usuario, así te causas problemas con privilegios en los logs en que escribes.

Una solución puede ser de dar este script `chown root:root`, ejecutable solamente para root, y luego envolverlo en otro script que no es modificable para el usuario, y lo ejecuta usando `sudo`. En `sudoers` permites ejecución de este otro script para todos, y tienes tu riesgo de seguridad tapado. :)

Más fácil aun (sin los problemas de seguridad) sería usar `who - u` en una manera similar, que te da resultados similares, unicamente vas a tener que cambiar la posición en el segundo `awk` para obtener la IP.